# How can I do conditional rendering on a styled component?

Tags: reactjs

I am using conditional rendering to make toggle function. But I think there is a problem with the method because I did conditional rendering on the styled component but it doesn't work. Can you tell me how to fix it? I'd appreciate it if you let me know thanks

**my.jsx:**

If I click on another image, the value of the `profile` becomes false, and if I click on the `profile` image, the value of the `profile` becomes true. And according to the value of the profile, I gave the value of the display by conditional rendering the tag whose className is `IconWrap6True`. But now, the display value of IconWrap6Trued keeps coming out as block, and 'none' is not applied. The cord is long, so I skipped the parts that I didn't need

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import defaultProfile from '../resources/images/img/defaultprofile.jpg'


const NavigationBarWrap1 = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: stretch;



  .IconWrap6True {
    ${props => props.profile ? "block" : "none"};
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: 2px solid rgb(38,38,38);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  }



`

function NavigationBar() {

  //state 
  const[home, setHome] = useState(true);
  const[profile,setProfile] = useState(true); 

  //true
  const setTrueHome = () => {
    setHome(true)
  }

  const setTrueProfile = () => {
    setProfile(true)
  }

  //false
  const setFalseHome = () => {
    setHome(false)
  }


  const setFalseProfile = () => {
    setProfile(false)
  }
  
    //handle
   const forHome = (e) => {
    setTrueHome();
    setFalseProfile();
   }

   const forProfile = (e) => {
    setFalseHome();
    setTrueProfile();
   }

  return (
    <NavigationBarWrap1>
              <div className='IconWrap'>
                    <div className='IconWrap4'>
                      <div onClick={forHome} className='IconWrap5'>
                        <div>
                          <div className='IconWrap6'>
                            <div className='IconWrap7'>
                              {home===true?
                              <>
                                <img/>
                              </>:
                              <>
                                <img/>
                              </>}
                              
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
              <div className='IconWrap'>
                <div className='IconWrap2'>
                  <div>
                    <div className='IconWrap6'>
                      <div profile={profile} className='IconWrap6True'/>
                      <div onclick={forProfile} className='IconWrap7'>
                        <img src={defaultProfile}/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='textWrap'>
                    <div className='textWrap2'>
                      <div className='textWrap3'>
                        프로필
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
    </NavigationBarWrap1>
  )
}

export default NavigationBar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the profile prop to `NavigationBarWrap1`

```
<NavigationBarWrap1 profile={profile}>
```

Comment: Sorry, it was really easy. It applies well. Thank you!